# Excel Conditional Formating: Comparing columns of data?

Tags: excel

**Background:**

I have two columns D and J which are supposed to contain the same value.

Column D is a Calculation (e.g. =ROUND(1.704 * 1.989437,2)

Column J is a VLOOKUP of the static value, that should match D (e.g. 3.39)

**Question:**

How do I compare the 2500+ rows to see if the values match in the corresponding cells, or that D = J, with formatting?  (I have another column P that contains whether they are the same, but I want the value in D to be highlighted.)

Comment: Do you want to highlight the ones that match, or the ones that don't match?

Answer (score 2):

Create a conditional formatting rule =$D2=$J2 in while D2 being highlighted, and change the "applies to" from D2 to D2:D2502, assmuming you have values starting in row 2.

Or =$D2<>$J2 if you want to show them not matching.